# Reading an updated file in Properties.Resources

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC 4 project, in which I stored a template file (foo.txt) inside /Contents.

Afterwards, I added the file in Properties.Resources and I am accessing it through Properties.Resources.foo.

My problem is that if I update foo.txt after publishing, the application still returns the old content of the file.

How can I access the latest content, without recompiling?

Comment: The compiler will not do anything with the foo.txt file, before or after publishing. Are you updating the foo.txt in the pre-publish location? Is the change on that you can carry out programatically, so that the published foo.txt is amended in the first place?

Comment: I am editing the file in the published location, but the change is not visible in the app. The weird thing is that the designer file keeps a reference to that file, and the relative path is correct.. :|